# Convert binary string back to binary (python 3+)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, binary

I have a string like so:

```
initial = b"data|22|b'or ac mattis blandit, elit mi ullamcorper tellus, id eleifend enim augue in ipsum.'|1358186458"
```

and getting its contents like so:

```
first, second, third, fourth = initial.decode().split('|')
```

the `third` variable is of type string () but I want to convert it back to binary without re-wrapping it.

the third variable contents are:

```
"b'or ac mattis blandit, elit mi ullamcorper tellus, id eleifend enim augue in ipsum.'"
```

Note that the type for `third` is still string, but I want this back to binary!

Comment: Neither `b` nor `'` have any special meaning within a string. `"b'or"` is simply a string o 4 characters. If you want to convert it to a binary, `.encode()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `decode`ing and then `encode`ing back, use the `bytes` equivalent of `.split` which requires a bytes string to be passed as a delimiter:

```
first, second, third, fourth = initial.split(b'|')
```

With `third` now being:

```
>>> print(third)
b"b'or ac mattis blandit, elit mi ullamcorper tellus, id eleifend enim augue in ipsum.'"
```

if you don't need the `b''` in the binary string, trim it off:

```
>>> third[2:-1]
b'or ac mattis blandit, elit mi ullamcorper tellus, id eleifend enim augue in ipsum.'
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt realize it was this easy with the `.split(b'|')`

Comment: `bytes` support the (almost all of the) same operations as `str`s do just with the equivalent `bytes` arguments, next time you need to operate on `bytes` and need `bytes` as a result, no need to `decode/encode` if you want `bytes`.